# How to get the contents of the error page in Python's mechanize?

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

So assume I get an error back when using `mechanize.Browser.retrieve` and I catch it like this:

```
try:
  br.retrieve(url, fname)
except mechanize.HTTPError as e:
  if e.code in [403, 404]:
    # how can I get to the contents of the server-sent error page?
  else:
    raise
```

How can I access the error page which was sent by the server at this point?

I've tried using `br.response().get_data()`, but that doesn't seem to get populated when using `retrieve()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since HTTP errors are wrapped by `mechanize` and contain additional info about the response, you can use `e.read()`:

```
try:
    br.retrieve(url, fname)
except mechanize.HTTPError as e:
    if e.code in [403, 404]:
        print e.read()
    else:
        raise
```